# вызов метода внутри метода php

Tags: php

не могу понять почему ничего не выводится. Есть объявление, есть вызов с параметром

```
 $ff = 'ground zero';
function method1($a)
{
    echo($a);
}
function method2 ()
{
    method1($ff);
}
method2();
```

Answer (score 3):

Переменная $ff не объявлена внутри метода mathod2. Если хотите воспользоваться глобальной переменной внутри функции, явно объявите ее как глобальную:

```
$ff = 'ground zero';
function method1($a)
{
    echo($a);
}
function method2 ()
{
    global $ff;
    method1($ff);
}
method2();
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/EdPyCZ)

Подробнее в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php) PHP.

Comment: спасибо, исчерпывающий ответ